# Remove shadow from placeholder text in UITextField styled using CALayer

Tags: ios, uitextfield, calayer, placeholder, shadow

I've created a UITextField from the Interface Builder(IB).
Since I wanted custom styling, I selected the None styling in IB.
On viewDidLoad, I'm assigning it the following style:

```
txtEmail.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
txtEmail.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:199.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
txtEmail.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
txtEmail.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
txtEmail.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.17;
txtEmail.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-0.9,0.9);
txtEmail.layer.shadowRadius = 1.1;

// This is to provide a left padding for None styled textfields
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
txtEmail.leftView = paddingView;
txtEmail.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Now my textfield is getting perfectly styled, but my placeholder text (provided in IB) is also inheriting that shadow. How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the below code its working fine, you need to remove `shadowRadius`

```
txtEmail.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
txtEmail.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
txtEmail.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:199.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
txtEmail.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
txtEmail.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
txtEmail.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.17;
txtEmail.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-0.9,0.9);
txtEmail.layer.masksToBounds = false;

// This is to provide a left padding for None styled textfields
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
txtEmail.leftView = paddingView;
txtEmail.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[self.view addSubview:txtEmail];
```

[image]